# A way to do something is (to do something)/(doing something)/(by doing something)?

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-structure

Which ones are correct and how do they differ?

1. > A better way to curb crime is to provide free education.
2. > A better way to curb crime is providing free education.
3. > A better way to curb crime is by providing free education.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the “by doing y” construction sounds more natural when it follows “You do x” or “One does x” than in the comparative example given (“A better way to do x is by doing y.”) That’s because in “You do [x] by doing [y]” the “by doing [y]” phrase isn’t an adverb describing the manner of performing [x], but a proposition that “doing [y] will accomplish [x].” But “You do [x] by doing [y]” is a sentence with an *active* verb (“You do”).

But when the verb of the sentence, as here, is simply “is”, the sentence basically operates to create what in math is called an equation (12-3 = 9). You’re basically saying one thing *is* another thing (this is true even when you’re saying, as here, that the second thing is “an example of” the first thing). In the same way that it shouldn’t matter which side of the = you put each expression in an equation (you can also say 9 = 12-3), it shouldn’t matter grammatically which side of the “is” each clause appears on in a sentence that says one thing is another thing.

So let’s reverse the clauses and see if it still sounds right.

“To provide free education is a better way to curb crime.”
“Providing free education is a better way to curb crime.”
“By providing free education is a better way to curb crime.”

“By” in the 3rd sentence sounds very very wrong. The preposition turns “providing free education” into an adverbial phrase that cannot serve as the subject of a sentence, that cannot stand on either side of the “is” in an equivalence sentence. For an equivalence sentence, we need two *nouns* on either side of the “is” (the gerund or infinitive can both serve the function of a noun).

However, “By providing free education, we curb crime” or “By providing free education, crime is curbed” both work. In the first, the subject “we” performs the active verb “curb”, “crime” is the object, and “by providing free education” is an adverbial phrase that describes how we curb crime. In the second, even tho it uses the passive voice “crime is curbed” the implied subject doing the curbing is society, and again, “by providing free education” is an adverbial phrase that describes how that curbing is accomplished. Even though the second sentence uses “is”, it’s not an equivalence sentence; that “is” forms the passive voice predicate “is curbed”, rather than standing like an = between two equal expressions.

To me that demonstrates that “by [x]ing” is NOT always equivalent to “[x]ing” or “to [x].” The first two sentences in the OP question are more or less correct and identical in meaning (though for the sake of parallelism, one might wish to say “A better way of curbing crime is providing free education” or “A better way to curb crime is to provide free education”, and some grammarians would ding you for not using parallel structures). The third is grammatically suspect *at best*.

Answer (score 0):

They are all identical in meaning.

To [x]", and, "By [x]ing" are always direct equivalent.

The 'by' in the third example is just an option.

Comment: Can you say more about in what context "to X" and "by Xing" are always directly equivalent, and how specifically "Xing" is different from those two?